# Util.class, in intelliJ, giving me sources not found message

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I receive a prompt that `sources not found` and when I click `download sources` nothing happens.

[util.class file http://snag.gy/u4Bgw.jpg](http://snag.gy/u4Bgw.jpg)

when I click `attach sources`, it points at the `mysql-connector-java` file.

[attach source image http://snag.gy/HGjPQ.jpg](http://snag.gy/HGjPQ.jpg)

but I still get the `sources not found` message. Am I pointing in the wrong place?

**edited:** added image to display maven tab

[maven repository tab in IntelliJ http://snag.gy/IVYKj.jpg](http://snag.gy/IVYKj.jpg)

Comment: Are the sources available? Do you have access to a maven repo with the sources?

Comment: when I click on the Maven Projects tab, I see this screen http://snag.gy/IVYKj.jpg. Not sure how else to check if the sources are available

Comment: Go to http://mvnrepository.com/ and search for the library you're interested in. Check the artifacts to see if a source jar is available. Also, I can't hit any site from work, other than SO, so links to images don't work for me -- add the image to the question if you think it's relevant.

Comment: good to know, I'll make a habit of doing that. added the image to question